# Delay when attempting to end an HKWorkoutSession in WatchOS 5

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I'm testing out my code that starts an `HKWorkoutSession` collects samples and ends then saves the workout using the old `HKWorkoutConfiguration` API (not the new `HKWorkoutBuilder` API)....my understanding is that the previous API should still work.

However when testing in the watch simulator, starting and stopping a workout using Xcode 10 Beta 4 and 5, I noticed that I am able to start a workout and query samples, however when I call `healthStore.stop` there is a 5 or 6 second delay until the workout ends?

```
// Create workout configuration
        let workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
        workoutConfiguration.activityType = .running
        workoutConfiguration.locationType = .outdoor

        do {
            workoutSession = try HKWorkoutSession(configuration: workoutConfiguration)
            workoutSession?.delegate = self

        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription) 
        }

func start(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession) {
        healthStore.start(workoutSession)
    }

    func end(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession) {
        healthStore.end(workoutSession)
    }
```

Update 9/20/18: I filed a radar, it was marked as dup....as of Xcode 10 GM release this bug is still present.  Confirmed this does NOT happen on device, only simulator.

Comment: I'd recommend you file a bug with Apple.

Comment: @Allan will do, wasn't sure if this was part of the HealthKit API deprecations